# Retrieving data with Firebase Swift bug

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
@IBAction func one_2(sender: AnyObject) {
    if un_1.textColor == UIColor.blueColor() {
        if aac == false {


            var aa = [FIRDataSnapshot]()
            DataService.ds.REF_ISSUELIKES.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    for snap in snapshots {
                        aa.append(snap)
                    }
                    print(aa[0])

                    var aaUpvotes = String()
                    var aaDownvotes = String()
                    let a = Array(String(aa[0]).characters)
                    if a.count == 55 {
                        aaUpvotes = String(a[51])
                        aaDownvotes = String(a[34])
                    } else if a.count == 57 {
                        aaDownvotes = String("\(a[34])\(a[35])")
                        aaUpvotes = String("\(a[52])\(a[53])")
                    } else if a.count == 59 {
                        aaDownvotes = String("\(a[34])\(a[35])\(a[36])")
                        aaUpvotes = String("\(a[53])\(a[54])\(a[55])")
                    }

                    self.ref.child("IssueLikes").child("Abortion").child("Upvotes").setValue(Int(aaUpvotes)! + 1)
                    self.ref.child("IssueLikes").child("Abortion").child("Downvotes").setValue(Int(aaDownvotes)! - 1)
                }
            })

            aab = false
            un_1.text = String(Int(un_1.text!)!-1)
            un_2.text = String(Int(un_2.text!)!+1)
            un_1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            un_2.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            aac = true

        } else {
            print("AAC")
        }
    } else if un_1.textColor == UIColor.whiteColor() {
        if aac == false {


            var aa = [FIRDataSnapshot]()
            DataService.ds.REF_ISSUELIKES.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    for snap in snapshots {
                        aa.append(snap)
                    }
                    print(aa[0])

                    var aaUpvotes = String()
                    var aaDownvotes = String()
                    let a = Array(String(aa[0]).characters)
                    if a.count == 55 {
                        aaUpvotes = String(a[51])
                        aaDownvotes = String(a[34])
                    } else if a.count == 57 {
                        aaDownvotes = String("\(a[34])\(a[35])")
                        aaUpvotes = String("\(a[52])\(a[53])")
                    } else if a.count == 59 {
                        aaDownvotes = String("\(a[34])\(a[35])\(a[36])")
                        aaUpvotes = String("\(a[53])\(a[54])\(a[55])")
                    }

                    self.ref.child("IssueLikes").child("Abortion").child("Upvotes").setValue(Int(aaUpvotes)! + 1)
                }
            })

            aab = false
            un_2.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            un_2.text = String(Int(un_2.text!)!+1)
            aac = true

        } else {
            print("AAC")
        }
    } else {
        if aac == false {


            var aa = [FIRDataSnapshot]()
            DataService.ds.REF_ISSUELIKES.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    for snap in snapshots {
                        aa.append(snap)
                    }
                    print(aa[0])

                    var aaUpvotes = String()
                    var aaDownvotes = String()
                    let a = Array(String(aa[0]).characters)
                    if a.count == 55 {
                        aaUpvotes = String(a[51])
                        aaDownvotes = String(a[34])
                    } else if a.count == 57 {
                        aaDownvotes = String("\(a[34])\(a[35])")
                        aaUpvotes = String("\(a[52])\(a[53])")
                    } else if a.count == 59 {
                        aaDownvotes = String("\(a[34])\(a[35])\(a[36])")
                        aaUpvotes = String("\(a[53])\(a[54])\(a[55])")
                    }

                    self.ref.child("IssueLikes").child("Abortion").child("Upvotes").setValue(Int(aaUpvotes)! + 1)
                }
            })

            aab = false
            un_1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            un_2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            un_2.text = String(Int(un_2.text!)!+1)
            un_2.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            aac = true

        } else {
            print("AAC")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from my code, I am trying to update Firebase with new values when buttons are clicked. What happens, however, is when I click these buttons, the Firebase values in the database go crazy, going from 1 to 0 every millisecond.

I have checked my code multiple times over and just cannot find anything wrong with it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observer initialization does not belong in `@IBAction` handlers.

Once they are set, they remain valid throughout the lifetime of the parent `UIViewController`, or perhaps the lifetime of the entire App -- check documentation. So you have many observers registered to the event, all duplicates -- an additional duplicate every time the button is clicked.

Observers should be set up at `viewDidLoad()` and removed at `deinit`, or conversely at `viewWillAppear` and removed at `viewDidDisappear`.

An aside your identifier names are totally cryptic, almost as if they were chosen to deliberately obfuscate. This slows down your own mental processes as well as everyone who sees your code or tries to help.

Comment: Ahhh, that helps immensly. And about the cryptic identifier names, it is a big app, and it is actually a organized way if you say the whole thing. Thanks a lot.